# On-demand SSL Cert key loading

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

We have a requirement where the certificate keys need to be loaded only in Nginx memory. That is, saving it in the local FS is not an option. Also, we need the cert key to be present in Nginx memory only when there are active lookups to it (requests to the virtual server using the cert). When there are no requests, the cert key should be flushed from the memory and reloaded from a KMS (key mgmt server) on-demand through client authentication (Nginx authenticating to the KMS as a client). Pls provide pointers if you have insight into such or a similar requirement.

I referred to best practices in this Nginx [blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/protecting-ssl-private-keys-nginx-hashicorp-vault/#update-web-server-config-nginx). However, not all of our requirements are met. There are a few questions:

1. Does the ngx_http_ssl_module load the certificate on demand or during config parse? Once loaded, does it always stay in memory, whether used or not?
2. Is it possible to load the certificate key through a sub-request on-demand (that is when SSL hand-shake is initiated)?